# What is the lightest way to load search results via Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, sunspot

This is a question of general strategy. I've been pinging load time for a search results page I'm doctoring with sunspot_rails, and I've noticed some strange discoveries.

1. Sometimes results load faster, if other things are loaded with them.
2. The more I can avoid join tables, the lighter I can tap the database.

I'm curious if I'm missing some other great staples as well. Here's an example of a search result I'm parsing with comments on the average load time that item takes if I isolate it and load it by itself.

```
All things Commented out = Completed in 554ms (View: 487, DB: 16)
All things loaded = Completed in 9093ms (View: 9008, DB: 37)
```

**The Search Image**

```
.left.search_image_holder
  - if result.search_image.exists?
    = image_tag result.search_image.url(:thumb)
  - elsif result.logo.exists?
    = image_tag result.logo.url(:thumb)
  - else
    = image_tag 'search_image_default.jpg'

Completed in 5791ms (View: 5728, DB: 10)
```

**The Basic Info**

```
.grid_3.omega
  %h1<
    = link_to truncate(result.name.titleize, :length => 30), organization_path(result.hq_url.blank? ? result : result.hq_url), :title => "Find out more about #{result.name} in #{result.city}"
  .clear
  %h3<
    =h result.city.titleize
  .clear
  .class7
    =h truncate(result.quick_description.titleize, :length => 60)
  .clear

Completed in 4158ms (View: 3979, DB: 16)
```

**Icons**

```
.grid_4.omega.alpha
  .left{:style => 'margin-right: 12px; width: 40px'}
    - if result.contact_24
      = link_to image_tag('24hr-icon.png'), contact_organization_path(result), :title => "This local business or organization guarentees tocontact you within 24 hours"
    - else
      &nbsp;
  .left{:style => 'margin-right: 12px; width: 40px'}
    - if result.deals.count > 0
      = link_to image_tag('hq-card-icon.png'), view_organization_deals_path(result), :title => "This local business or organization features promotions, deals, or steals"
    - else
      &nbsp;
  .left{:style => 'margin-right: 12px; width: 40px'}
    - if result.video_count > 0
      = link_to image_tag('videos-icon.png'), organization_path(result.hq_url.blank? ? result : result.hq_url, :show_video => true), :title => "This local business or organization features a video"
    - else
      &nbsp;
  - if result.reviews.count > 0
    %a{:href => organization_reviews_path(result)}
      .left.star_rating_icon
        = result.rating
  .clear

Completed in 4125ms (View: 3929, DB: 36)
```

**About Text**

```
.grid_4.omega.alpha{:style => 'height: 25px; overflow: hidden;'}
  %p<
    = truncate(sanitize(simple_format(result.about_us), :tags => ''), :length => 100).titleize

Completed in 4500ms (View: 4311, DB: 12)
```

Comment: for one thing, you're using haml and a grid layout. but why the inline styles?!

Comment: @corroded Would that effect loadtime?

Comment: if ever, just miniscule. im just commenting on the styles, as they should be in a separate file. if there are lots of pages and they all have that much styles, yes it will affect load time by some milliseconds

Answer (score 1):

One way you can speed things up is to pre-calculate the results of

```
truncate(sanitize(simple_format(result.about_us), :tags => ''), :length => 100).titleize
```

That way your view is just spitting out text/html. You'd have a before_save method that does the above into another field.

But that's just a guess -- it does seem that your views are loading too slowly, so this *might* be the cause.